# Облачный синтез речи

Tags: google-translate

Есть ли у Google api для проговаривания определённого текста ( как в Google Translate). Т.е. например отсылаешь строку - получаешь wav/mp3/ogg etc.
Можно не Google а любых других - главное не локальный синтез речи, а облачный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google использует синтезатор речи компании Phonetic Arts. Это один из лучших синтезаторов. Вы вполне можете работать именно с ним через Google Tranlate: то есть отсылать строку типа

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=something
```

и получать в итоге файл. Пример того, как это делается, [на Ruby](https://github.com/c2h2/tts#readme).

Comment: Очень хорошо! Есть ли аналоги ?